# Prove at least one of the numbers $e+\pi$ and $e\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: field-theory

Assume  that $\pi$ and $e$ are  both  transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have proved $e$ and $\pi$ are both algebraic over the field $\mathbb{Q}(e+\pi, e\pi)$. The polynomial is $p(x)=x^2-(e+\pi)x+e\pi$

Now I need to deduce that at least one of the numbers $e+\pi$ and $e\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Any help?

Comment: If they are both algebraic, what can you say about $\mathbb Q(e, \pi)$?

Comment: A simpler way to look at it: consider the quadratic equation whose roots are $e$ and $\pi$. What can you say about its coefficients?

Comment: @MichaelWeiss They are algebraic? So the roots must be algebraic . Contradiction?

Comment: That's it, Bob!

Comment: Unfortunately, we neither know whether $e\pi$ is transcendental, nor whether $e+\pi$ is transcendental. But this is a consequence of the widely believed Schanuel's conjecture. It is not even known whether $e\pi$ is irrational or whether $e+\pi$ is irrational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can generalize the result as follows :

Suppose, $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers, at least one of which is transcendental. Then, at least one of $a+b$ and $ab$ is transcendental:

Otherwise the polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$ would have algebraic coefficients.

Since it is well known that the field of algebraic numbers is algebraically closed, we could conclude that the roots (which are $a$ and $b$) are both algebraic, contradicting our assumption.

Comment: This argument works for any pair of transcendental numbers $a$ and $b$. At least one of $a+b$ or $ab$ must be transcendental.  Otherwise if both $a+b$ and $ab$ are algebraic, then as $a$ and $b$ are roots of $x^2 - (a+b)x +ab=0$, both would have to be algebraic. More generally, given any $n$ transcendental numbers ${a_1},\cdots,{a_n}$, if we form the $n$ elementary symmetric polynomials using them, at least one of these polynomial expressions would have to be transcendental.